# Android make re-usable layout

Tags: android-layout

I'm rather fed-up of copying this code around.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- stuff goes here -- usually more layouts -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way of making it re-usable, like:

```
<BoxWithTitleLayout
  android:layout_weight="1"
  title="Title"
>
<!-- stuff -->
</BoxWithTitleLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could Use the [!LayoutInflater] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to create a view based on your layout template, and then inject it into the view where you need it

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

// fill in any details dynamically here
TextView textView = (TextView) 
v.findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);
textView.setText("your text");

// insert into main view
ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) 
findViewById(R.id.insert_point);
insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```